# nifi avro - cant find package namespace defined in schema

Tags: json, avro, apache-nifi

Im new to NiFi and Avro and I am tasked with figuring out if its of any use for my team's needs. I am trying to using NiFi to convert Json to Avro but I keep getting the following error on the bulletin board during the conversion (N.B. I am using 'ConvertRecord' processor with JsonTreeReader and AvroRecordSetWriter):

> will route to failure: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of com.product.subproduct.function.productID in field messageId of com.product.subproduct.function.Message

Below is a snapshot of the schema:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Message",
  "namespace" : "com.product.subproduct.function",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "messageId",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "record",
      "name" : "productID",
      "fields" : [ {
        "name" : "subproductId",
        "type" : {
          "type" : "record",
          "name" : "subproductId",
          "fields" : [ {
            "name" : "value",
            "type" : "string"
          }, {
            "name" : "type",
            "type" : "string"
          } ]
        }
      }, {
        "name" : "accountId",
        "type" : "string"
      }, {
        "name" : "entityId",
        "type" : "string"
      }, {
        "name" : "clientId",
        "type" : "string"
      } ]
    }
  }
```

Do I need to provide full path to the namespace in the schema or is there a key step I've missed?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is saying that the productId field is null, it would be helpful if you could provide example json that you are trying to process.

Comment: Adding to what Bryan had suggested, can you try to build the Avro schema from your sample input, using the `InferAvroSchema` processor and use that schema in your `RecordReader/Writer` controller services?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman Your suggestion worked, thank you.